# Issue with Google Cloud Platform(GCP) DNS zones and openshift

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, openshift, google-cloud-dns

I have followed the instructions at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/installing/installing_gcp/installing-gcp-account.html#installation-gcp-dns_installing-gcp-account for setting up an openshift trial.
All steps I managed to get working excpet for DNS steps mentioned.
I created a zone my-new-zone for my subdomain in GCP clusters.mysite.com and pointed DNS NS's to google (ns-cloud-**d**[1-4].googledomains.com) and I am able to interact with my openshift just fine.
However, in so doing, all of my other DNS entries for mysite.com no longer function.
I tried creating a second zone my-zone in GCP for mysite.com and added those preexisting entries there, but they came up with different GCP DNS NS servers (ns-cloud-**a**[1-4].googledomains.com).

How can I fix this so that I can access the openshift and also access my original sites?

Note: I can destroy and recreate the openshift cluster as needed at this point, but I need to know the correct steps for getting the DNS right.

---

Additional clarifications:

Note 1. I thought I had included above but apparently left out this detail: [mysite].com DNS entries were maintained at Dotster.com.  When I got to step 6 in the linked instructions, I had to call Dotster.com because I could not understand how to proceed.  I was told I could not use separate NS servers for the subdomain and they asked if I wanted to point the NS servers for my domain to the GCP servers indicated.  I agreed and they repointed the NS servers.  At that point I tried to add my DNS entries to GCP to restore access to my primary sites, and am not understanding how to do so.  GCP will not allow me to change the zone name from clusters.[mysite].com to [mysite].com.  It looked like all I needed to do was add another zone for [mysite].com, so I did so, not expecting the second zone would use totally different nameservers.

**PROBLEM**: **DNS does not work for primary domain** after setting up OpenShift on GCP.  My website is down, my email is down, all of my sites are down.

**Objective/Goal**: Restore DNS service for primary domain entries AND have OpenShift working correctly.

**Errors**:

```
$ nslookup www.[mysite].com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find www.[mysite].com: SERVFAIL
```

As for why I created a subdomain, I already had my domain set up at dotster.com.  I was following step 2 which says "2. Create a public hosted zone for your domain **or subdomain** in your GCP project. See Creating public zones in the GCP documentation.  Use an appropriate root domain, such as openshiftcorp.com, or subdomain, such as clusters.openshiftcorp.com."  And then I called dotster.com when I got to step 6 as I did not know how to proceed at that point.  Please see note 1 above.

Comment: Rewrite your post so that the problem, objective, errors, etc are clearly specified. As written I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish or what the problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree with @JohnHanley it will be better if you share us your goal that you want to achieve. Is there any reason why you created a zone only just to your subdomain? Because if there is a reason, you should consider step 6 from the link that you share under configuring dns for gcp.

Once you use or change the nameserver in your domain registrar it will follow the credentials where your nameserver is, for example your subdomain, that is the reason the root domain is no longer working. There is a way that you can have both in one zone but again, it depends on your goal.

Comment: Hi @YvanG. From your comment it sounds like my goal is to have both in one zone.  I think I was tripped up in step 2 of the linked instructions.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I have added a section breaking out the problem objective and errors.  My apologies for not being more clear in the original post.

Comment: I suggest to create zone in your root domain, once created, add "A record" using your root domain then add "cname record" for subdomain. Once done, get the nameserver and place it in your domain registrar. Make sure to add other necessary record to the zone that you created in order for other service to work like email. Propagation will take at least 24 to 48 hours depends on DNS server.

Comment: Hi, any update from this concern?

Comment: Hi @YvanG. I did succeed by starting over and first creating my zone with the root domain.  Thank you.

Comment: That is great to hear, since creating zone using your root domain solved this concern I will be posting it as answer for the awareness of the other users.

Comment: Just stumbled back across this.  I am dismayed to see that my post was modified by someone else, removing "commentary".  Seems free speech is not an objective here.

Comment: @SwaJime - StackOverflow prefers to-the-point details, not extra commentary and fluff. However, when your question was edited, you were notified. You can reject (rollback) an edit to your question. Note: the changes have nothing to do with free speech. The details of you question were not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create zone in your root domain, once created, add "A record" using your root domain then add "cname record" for subdomain. Once done, get the nameserver and place it in your domain registrar. Make sure to add other necessary record to the zone that you created in order for other service to work like email. Propagation will take at least 24 to 48 hours depends on DNS server.